# Is it possible to create a serial queue across multiple ViewControllers in swift

Tags: swift, firebase, concurrency, google-cloud-firestore

I have a series of `ViewControllers` which each are uploading data to `Firebase`. I would like to know is if it is possible to create a serial queue which would ensure that they are uploading in the order that the view controllers are displayed. Would I have to create a delegate method to do something like this?

My `ViewController`s look like the following

VC 1:

```
class VC1: UIViewController{

   func nextVC(_ data: Data){
      db.collection("collection")
        .document("Document").setData([
           "data1": data
        ]){ err in
           if let err = err {
              print("Error writing document: \(err)")
           } else {
              print("Document successfully written!")
           }
       }
       self.performSegue(withIdentifier: K.firstSegue, sender: self)
   }
}
```

VC 2:

```
class VC2: UIViewController{

   func nextVC(_ data: Data){
      db.collection("collection")
        .document("Document").updateData([
           "data2": data
        ]){ err in
           if let err = err {
              print("Error writing document: \(err)")
           } else {
              print("Document successfully written!")
           }
       }
       self.performSegue(withIdentifier: K.secondSegue, sender: self)
   }
}
```

VC 3:

```
class VC3: UIViewController{

   func nextVC(_ data: Data){
      db.collection("collection")
        .document("Document").updateData([
           "data3": data
        ]){ err in
           if let err = err {
              print("Error writing document: \(err)")
           } else {
              print("Document successfully written!")
           }
       }
   }
}
```

**EDIT: for clarification**

The issue that I was having was that when I got to my third view controller I would get an error that the document I was trying to update did not exist. I thought that by adding all three `Firebase` calls to a `DispatchQueue` I could avoid this issue. This did work but I then had an issue with lag time between view controllers. What I am hoping is for the `ViewControllers` to add their data to a queue to upload to `Firebase` serially so that they up load in the proper order and for that to take place in the background so that it does not impact the UI.

Comment: "I would like to know is if it is possible to create a serial queue which would ensure that they are uploading in the order that the view controllers are displayed" Sure, just say `let queue = DispatchQueue(label:"myqueue")` in any file outside of any class declaration. But whether you can get Firebase to _use_ your queue, I have no idea.

Comment: How about performing the segues in the completion blocks?

Comment: @matt That is exactly what I was looking for. danh I tried that but ran into some strange errors.

Comment: I'll give it as an answer (slightly modified).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution to my problem. Since I was getting a lot of error regarding updating documents I decided to just upload all information at once which I did by passing all the required info to the last vc and uploading.

Answer (score 3):

The Firebase tasks are, themselves, asynchronous, so creating a queue will not guarantee anything other than ensuring that they’re initiated in order. But that’s not achieving anything more than if you just initiated them from the main thread. And you have no assurances that they’ll be received in order or finish in order.

If you really must have these run in order, you must move the initiation of the segue in the completion handler of the prior request. For example, consider:

```
func nextVC(_ data: Data){
    db.collection("collection").document("Document").setData(["data1": data]) { err in
        if let err = err {
            print("Error writing document: \(err)")
        } else {
            print("Document successfully written!")
        }
    }
    self.performSegue(withIdentifier: K.firstSegue, sender: self)
}
```

Change that to

```
func nextVC(_ data: Data){
    db.collection("collection").document("Document").setData(["data1": data]) { err in
        if let err = err {
            print("Error writing document: \(err)")
        } else {
            print("Document successfully written!")
            self.performSegue(withIdentifier: K.firstSegue, sender: self)
        }
    }
}
```

There are other patterns (asynchronous custom `Operation` subclass, Combine, etc.) but this is the simplest approach.

Comment: My problem with this is that I would like the UI to perform a segue while data is uploading, With this the data uploads then the segue occurs.

Comment: @Bjorn - Yep. I thought that’s what you wanted, to know whether the firebase succeeded or not before you proceeded. The answer that you’ve accepted, though, accomplishes absolutely nothing. You’re dealing with asynchronous tasks, so using a queue to initiate them provides no assurances whatsoever. Like I said, if you *really* want to know that the first firebase request completed before the second, but not have the segue wait, then use asynchronous `Operation` subclass or Combine. (By the way, _why_ do you want firebase to wait? That’s extremely unusual pattern and only complicates your code.)

Comment: Each view controller is updating the same document if VC2 runs before VC1 has created the document it fails to update because there is no document

Answer (score 2):

As far as the single serial queue issue is concerned, it's simply a matter of saying the thing you would normally say, namely

```
let queue = DispatchQueue(label:"myqueue")
```

...but say it *in the right place*. Why does place matter? Because place, in Swift, determines both *lifetime and scope*. You want a queue that all other code can see (global scope) and that will always exist (lifetime).

There are two chief ways to do this. One is to say that declaration *outside any class declaration*. For example, put it at the top of the *AppDelegate.swift* file, just after the `import` statement(s). That makes this a *pure global*. The simple name is available everywhere throughout your app's code.

The other way is make this a `static let` in some class or other type. This gives it global scope while also namespacing it nicely. For example:

```
struct GlobalQueues { // or this could be an enum
    static let firebaseQueue = DispatchQueue(label:"myqueue") 
}
```

The result is that you can refer anywhere in the app's code to `GlobalQueues.firebaseQueue`, which is nicer namespacing than a pure global. It makes no functional difference, but it clarifies what this thing is and where it "lives".

Comment: However please note that, as I said in my comment, I do not guarantee that this will have any effect on Firebase loading. What you're trying to do is just wrong; what happens in the interface and what happens on the Internet need to be completely decoupled! The problem of doing something at the time of a view controller navigation is a serious problem, and you're not going to solve it merely by waving a serial queue at it.